# Why doesn't XML::Twig call my end_tag_handler?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I try to call subroutine for each tag, but the `end_tag_handlers` is never invoked.
My aim is a this sequence:

---sequence---
when `<auto>` call `\&loading`.
when `<apps><title>` call `\&kicks`.
when `<apps><logs>` call `\&bye`.
when `<apps>` call `\&app`.
when `<apps><title>` call `\&kicks`.
when `<apps><logs>` call `\&bye`.
when `<apps>` call `\&app`.
when `</auto>` call `\&finish`. → ***It was not called.***

**temp.pl:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use XML::Twig;
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
            start_tag_handlers => 
              { 'auto' => \&loading
              },
            twig_handlers =>
              { 'apps/title' => \&kicks,
                'apps/logs' => \&bye
              },
            twig_roots =>
              { 'apps' => \&app
              },
            end_tag_handlers => 
              { 'auto' => \&finish
              }
            );
$twig -> parsefile( "doc.xml");

  sub loading {
    print "---loading--- \n";
  }

  sub kicks {
    my ($twig, $elt) = @_;
    print "---kicks--- \n";
    print $elt -> text;
    print " \n";
  }

  sub app {
    my ($twig, $apps) = @_;
    print "---app--- \n";
    print $apps -> text;
    print " \n";
  }

  sub bye {
  my ($twig, $elt) = @_;
  print "---bye--- \n";
  print $elt->text;
  print " \n";
  }

  sub finish {
    print "---fishish--- \n";
  }
```

**doc.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<auto>
  <apps>
    <title>watch</title>
    <commands>set,start,00:00,alart,end</commands>
    <logs>csv</logs>
  </apps>
  <apps>
    <title>machine</title>
    <commands>down,select,vol_100,check,line,end</commands>
    <logs>dump</logs>
  </apps>
</auto>
```

**output:**

```
C:\>perl temp.pl
---loading---
---kicks---
watch
---bye---
csv
---app---
watchset,start,00:00,alart,endcsv
---kicks---
machine
---bye---
dump
---app---
machinedown,select,vol_100,check,line,enddump
```

I would like more here.

```
---finish---
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs for [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig/Twig.pm):

> `end_tag_handlers`
>
> A hash { expression => \&handler}. Sets element handlers that are called when the element 
>   is closed (at the end of the XML::Parser End handler). The handlers are called with 2 
>   params: the twig and the tag of the element.
>
> `twig_handlers` are called when an element is completely parsed, so why have this redundant 
>   option? There is only one use for `end_tag_handlers`: when using the `twig_roots` option, to 
>   trigger a handler for an element outside the roots.

You're setting up an end handler for your `auto` element, which is the root.  And you're only using `twig_roots` for `apps`.  So the end handler will never be called.

You should install your handler using `twig_handlers` instead.

So try this:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
        start_tag_handlers => 
          { 'auto' => \&loading
          },
        twig_handlers =>
          { 'apps/title' => \&kicks,
            'apps/logs' => \&bye,
            'auto'      => \&finish
          },
        twig_roots =>
          { 'apps' => \&app
          },
        );
```

Comment: Thank you very much,It was really work. And I had question about XML::Twig before and I read doc again,Alas my English skills also problem...Now really understand start_tag_handlers section in XML::Twig doc by your answer.

Comment: it seems that users tend to use twig_roots way too much. I actually seldom use it myself. I will add something about it in the docs.